# Problem with add/remove class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to create a menu navigation sort of like tab's but with vertical buttons..   When I start the page, the first li class is removed and when I click any other link nothign happens other then my content div's being shown..

The first link should always be active on page start.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var tabContainers = $('div.pages > div');

    $('div.sidemenu ul.list a').click(function () {
        tabContainers.hide().filter(this.hash).show();

        $('div.sidemenu ul.list li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        return false;
    }).filter(':first').click();


});
</script>
<div class="sidemenu">
  <ul class="list"> 
 <li class="active"><a href="#first">Login & Password</a></li>
 <li><a href="#second">Contact Details</a></li>
 <li><a href="#third">Company & Branch Details</a></li>
 <li><a href="#forth">Address Details</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="pages">
  <div id="first">
    CONTENT 1
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    CONTENT 2
  </div>
  <div id="third">
    CONTENT 3
  </div>
  <div id="forth">
    CONTENT 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Not sure what I am missing here..  Maybe its cuase I just woke up and still on my first cup of coffee.. ;)

Comment: If you're making custom components/scripts for jQuery read this article. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring it maybe a bit intimidating for beginning users but it's really powerful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding the class to the `<a>` element, but removing it from its parent `<li>` element.

```
$(this).addClass('active');  // "this" is the <a> that received the event

   // This removes "active" from the <li>
$('div.sidemenu ul.list li').removeClass('active');
```

Looks like you intend for the `<li>` to have the class. So you'd do this instead:

```
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
```

Or if you don't mind me mixing a little DOM API in:

```
$(this.parentNode).addClass('active');
```

*Now go get a refill! ;o)*

Comment: Ok.. I have to blame it on the lack of coffee! lol  Thanks!  I haven't used DOM much, any good resources to learn from?

Comment: @Dennis: Much of what I've learned has come from browsing through [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html) and trying things out. It gives a nice overview of browser compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

you add the "active" class to the A-Element

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```

i guess you want to add it to the LI-Element, so either you add

```
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
```

or you register the onclick on the LI-Element